# Help changing active to passive voice in this sentence?

Tags: passive-voice, clauses, active-voice

What would be the passive of the sentence?

> He will have eaten the whole mango by the time I eat a single piece.

Simply, I want to know that what would be the change in time clause, other than today, yesterday, etc.

Comment: Can you explain what the "change in time clause" has to do with passive voice? A change from active to passive voice is a matter of agency, not tense.

Comment: If you're learning English, see [ell.se]

Comment: This sentence has two transitive clauses. Passive can happen to either clause or to both. Which one is "the passive" of the sentence?

Comment: We can passivise the main clause: "The whole mango will have been eaten (by him) by the time I eat a single piece", or we can passivise just the subordinate clause: He will have eaten the whole mango by the time a single piece has been eaten (by me)".